# which characters are allowed inside folder names but not inside terms

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, term-store

I have a SharePoint document library then I am using power automate to get the folder names created on the root folder and create terms inside the term store. so which characters are allowed inside folder name but not inside term, so i can remove them before creating the term?